# Centralized EhCache

Tags: apache-camel, ehcache, apache-karaf

We have different clients apps, each of them defines its own cache, but they want to access/manage their caches through HTTP (rest). In that context, all the caches are in a web server container (1 node not a cluster) that expose a web service rest API to manage/access the caches operations.

Several clients apps are accessing their own cache but all through the same web service rest interface.

We are having performance problems when a client app doing a massive load of the cache, probably due to the HTTP/REST and network overhead.

Does anybody know how to avoid this performance problem?

We are using Apache Karaf 4.1.5 as the container and Ehcache 2.x

Answer (score 3):

Why not have all client webapp using its own cache?

Calling a REST API on the same server to retrieve your dedicated cache feels like a huge waste of CPU cycle and useless networking.

Comment: the client apps are not in the same server, we want to expose a cache as a service to company internal clients. The clients apps are in different jvm o even they arent java clients, maybe python..

Comment: I would have said to use a Terracotta server instead to distribute the cache. However, this won't cover the python use-case. In your case, do a benchmark to make sure but I suspect you need to implement a bulk-load in your REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Put the cache in one bundle and expose it using an OSGi service. At runtime calling an OSGi service is as fast as calling a java method. Like Henri explained this should avoid the http and REST overhead.

Alternatively you could also have your cache as a library and instantiate it in each bundle that needs it. As I understand that you want your cache not to be shared this might work even better.

Comment: I can put the cache and expose it using OSGi but how the clients access to it ?? they are in differents jvm o even they arent java clients. Same for the second approach and also the clients want to access de their cache as a service.